# Setting z-limits in ggplot2 `geom_hex()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to manually set z-limits in `ggplot2` 2d bin functions such as `geom_hexbin()`?

For example;

```
library(ggplot2)    
dat <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000),
  y = rnorm(1000)
)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_hex()
```

Is there a way to manually set the z-limits? The intended effect is to manually control the points at which the colour scales begin and end.

Thank you!

For extra points, I would also like to change the colours of the colour scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `scale_fill_gradient`:

```
library(ggplot2)    
dat <- data.frame(
    x = rnorm(1000),
    y = rnorm(1000)
)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_hex() +
    scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(1, 2))
```

[image]